# Remote logging library versus software(logger)

Tags: c++

I am penning down the features that a remote logging
library might need when built from scratch.
I looked up this: http://www.aggsoft.com/serial-data-logger.htm

I wish to know that what differences can be between a
remote logging library and a remote logger software.

Few things that I thought of:
1. The library can be used in C++ programs to log error messages on the fly.
2. The library will require programming knowledge on the end user's part.
3. The software cannot be used "inside" a C++ program, so we won't be able to log the error messages on the fly? Not sure about this one.

**I would like to know that besides logging error messages, what are the things for which it makes sense to use the remote logging library? Sharing big files? Anything else than these two things?**

Secondly which is better in what way out of a library and a software - in the current case?

Comment: When you mention "remote logger software" are you referring to something running on a remote machine? If so, how will you connect to it? If they dont provide an API/SDK of some sort, then you will have to implement the connection/communication yourself, right? If so, then this is something else to consider.

Comment: @Brady Thanks for commenting - but see the softwrae I have linked to. I don't know yet how they do it. *"If they dont provide an API/SDK of some sort"* Who is "they" here? The software? I don't know how to go about all this - can you pen down some ideas please?

Comment: The software that you've have posted via link has nothing to do with remote logging. This is just a serial logger - not remote. Remote means that someone sends packets over the network, not UART. So what are you trying to achieve? Logging serial data or something that being sent over the network from one peer to another?

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs thanks for the enlightenment. I was under a wrong impression :( My question talks about "remote" logging as per your definition. But, still will the features not be similar in both cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the my comments to your question, I would think that a logging library would provide some sort of an API/SDK, whereas remote software would not. The same would hold true if its sending messages via TCP/UDP or a serial port. The difference between the 2 options would be how much coding you would have to do. That is, how much would you have to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: *"The same would hold true if its sending messages via TCP/UDP"* But in the case of library I will just provide the user one interface function. The user won't be dealing with the TCP and all. Right?

Comment: Right, a library should provide an API so you wont have to deal with TCP directly. Whereas a remote SW would most likely require you to have to develop the socket code yourself, assuming the SW doesnt provide some sort of an SDK.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, nearly all debug environment/tools support redirect the console output the serial port (using print, or other API). It usually not a a task of Application programmer.

There are other methods for "remote logging":

```
    1) syslog, syslog-ng 's remote service
    2) save log local, fetch using ftp
```

Comment: I think Windows does not provide that (let's skip Msys/Cygwin). Link above is Windows based software.

Comment: @Andrejs Cainikovs. Windows has API to write to "COM ports", you can wrapper it as  "print" tool in your programe. And Windows has Terminal tool.

Comment: Yes, but standard Windows environment does not provide tools to support console output redirect to serial port.